# Keep alive service when no activities are bounded on ICS

Tags: java, android, service, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I've created a service with a socket.io (a chat service) that has bidirectional comunication between itself and three activityes.

The service is started at the "Dashboard" activity and binded, and has to be running since the whole app closes. When I move to the "Chat" activity that shows connected users I'm unbinding "Dashboard" and bounding "Chat" to the service.

`onStartCommand()` returns START_STICKY.

When I'm binding I'm calling `bindService(i, this, 0)`

This is really working on froyo and gingerbread, but i've tested on ICS the service is stopped when "Dashboard" activity is unbinded, and onDestroy() method from service is called. 
I've tried everything, setting flag of bindService to Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE, modifying the START_STICKY value returned from onStartCommand, but i can't keep service alive between activities.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I've found the problem, in my phone i've the developer option for not mantaining activities when it's not visible, that was killing my service too. But now i'm wondering if it will crash on devices with less ram or an agressive task killer.

Comment: Services are rarely killed by android. Only in very very low memory situations would services be getting stopped. Task killer/"memory management" apps should not be used, as Android manages memory on its own (if you are afraid of users using then it is their own fault).

Comment: That's right it's not my fault if user has some app killer, if android only closes services on very low memory problem solved.
Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Tie the service to an ongoing notification.